# How to show title bar

Tags: swift, macos

How to show the Title Bar if it is not selected the option "Show Title Bar" in Attributes?

I can show/hide:

```
view.window?.titleVisibility = .visible
view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = false
```

But this does not work if "Show Title Bar" is not selected. How to show the title bar in that case?

Regular window with Title bar and rounded corners:
[image]

When I remove the Title bar, the rounded corners disappear:
[image]

Is it possible to have no Title bar (remove or hidden) and the window with rounded corners?

(Be aware that I can make the Title bar transparent but still occupies a space: [How to remove title bar and have rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67673620/how-to-remove-title-bar-and-have-rounded-corners))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.titled` to the window's `styleMask`.

```
view.window?.styleMask.insert(.titled)
```

Comment: It works well but with your code, the window loses its rounded corners. Do you know how to have rounded corners and not a title bar?

Comment: A screen shot of the problem would help.

Comment: your link makes the title bar transparent but it still occupies space. See the link I provide in my question for more details. How to remove title bar and have rounded corners