# How to remove title bar and have rounded corners

Tags: swift, macos

macOS, Swift

I can remove the title bar of a window with code:

```
view.window?.styleMask.remove(.titled)
```

But in that case, the window loses its regular rounded corners. Is there a way to remove the title bar with code without removing the rounded corners?

[image]

Another option is to put make the bar transparent. But the bar is still there and has an space:

```
self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
self.view.window!.titleVisibility = NSWindow.TitleVisibility.hidden
self.view.window!.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
self.view.window!.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
self.view.window!.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
```

To check I put an NSView with a top constraint of 0

[image]

What I need is the window with the rounded corners and without the title bar (or the bar hidden or that it takes no space...)

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```
    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    self.view.window!.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
    self.view.window!.titleVisibility = NSWindow.TitleVisibility.hidden
    self.view.window!.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
```

to get you something like
[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried that before asking but If I understand it does not remove the title bar, it makes it transparent. Is that right? This afects many things like click things behind, center things on the rest of the page... Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: Can you show what your looking for in the form of a pic?.